# Refreshing layout in multi page Dash app due to watchdog file event

Tags: python, plotly-dash, python-watchdog

I have a multi page Dash app.

app.py:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
...
```

I then have a page:

pages/resources.py:

```
dash.register_page(__name__, order=4, title='️ Resources')
```

Layout is defined as (note `table` which is a variable containing a HTML table):

```
def layout(**other_unknown_query_strings):
    return dbc.Container([... + table...])
```

I put an observer on a file (watchdog):

```
event_handler = FileChangeHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='resources_reserve.yaml', recursive=False)
observer.start()
```

Now in `FileChangeHandler` I change `table` and then want to trigger a refresh of the layout.

Is there any elegant way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's elegant but one idea would be to :

1. Keep track of the table last modification timestamp (global variable updated in `FileChangeHandler`).
2. In the layout, add :

   - A `dcc.Store` to keep track of the last time the layout refreshed.
   - A `dcc.Interval` component.
   - If you need to call `layout()` when refreshing, a container whose `children` is the output of that function.
3. Add a callback with the interval component as input, the store data as state, and the layout container children as output: compare the (global) table-changed timestamp and the (client) layout-refreshed timestamp and refresh if necessary, otherwise `raise PreventUpdate`.